# Dynamically created menu items position giving same item id in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, uinavigationitem

I have created menu items dynamically in navigation drawer by using following code.

```
   Menu m;
   navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        m = navigationView.getMenu();
        m.add("menu item 1");
        m.add("menu item 2");
```

which is working fine and items are being created dynamically. But when I want to get the position of clicked menu item it shows me "0" every time using following code.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    Toast.makeText(order.this , "pos is : " + id  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Kindly tell me where I am getting me wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Menu.add()` with more parameters.

From Documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,int,int,java.lang.CharSequence)

use:

```
MenuItem add (int groupId, 
                int itemId, 
                int order, 
                CharSequence title)
```

in your code give Unique `itemId` to each menuItem

```
menu.add(0, 0, 0, "menu item 1")
menu.add(0, 1, 0, "menu item 2")
menu.add(0, 2, 0, "menu item 3")
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you and especially stackoverflow, where we grow!